# Add mysql row to existing array

Tags: php, mysql

I have an existing array, and I want to add some items in it from a mysql row

```
        $extendedadmindetails = full_query("SELECT * FROM `tbladmins` WHERE `id`='{$_SESSION['adminid']}'");
        $extendedadmindetailsrow = mysql_fetch_assoc ($extendedadmindetails);

        array_push($apiresults, $extendedadmindetailsrow);
```

This returns an array in an array:

```
 Array
(
    [result] => success
    [adminid] => 1
    [name] => My Name
    [notes] => 
    [signature] => 
    [allowedpermissions] => My Name
    [departments] => 1
    [requesttime] => 2017-02-26 12:44:06
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [uuid] => sqdqsdqsdqsdq454
            [roleid] => 1
            [username] => Myname
            [password] => $dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
            [passwordhash] => $jghjghjghjghjghjghjghjghjg                
            [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
        )

)
```

while I need:

```
 Array
(
    [result] => success
    [adminid] => 1
    [name] => My Name
    [notes] => 
    [signature] => 
    [allowedpermissions] => My Name
    [departments] => 1
    [requesttime] => 2017-02-26 12:44:06
    [id] => 1
    [uuid] => sqdqsdqsdqsdq454
    [roleid] => 1
    [username] => Myname
    [password] => $dfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
    [passwordhash] => $jghjghjghjghjghjghjghjghjg        
    [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00


)
```

I believe I should use array_push to add to an existing array, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. Do I need to loop trough the extendedadmindetailsrow array and add items 1 by 1?
Any one can help me out with this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use of `array_merge` is better in case

```
// Considering your mysql is returning only 1 row
foreach ($extendedadmindetailsrow as $key => $row) {
  $arr = $row;
}

// after this if you will try array_push also that will work
$result = array_merge($apiresults, $arr);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
array_merge($apiresults, $extendedadmindetailsrow);
```

Answer (score 2):

You  can:

```
$result = $apiresults + $extendedadmindetailsrow;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge()`

```
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
```

Output will be

```
Array ( 
    [0] => red 
    [1] => green
    [2] => blue
    [3] => yellow
)
```